# How to add script files to a salesforce lightning application?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

When I'm adding script files to a lightning component i'm getting an error as 'script tags only allowed in templates: Source'. Is there another way to add script links to the lightning application?

Comment: This could be helped by some code. What did you attempt?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot include scripts with a script tag from a component.  You can only include them with a script tag from the app.

From the Lightning Components Developer’s Guide

> To reference a JavaScript library that you’ve uploaded as a static resource, use a `<script>` tag in your .app resource.

There are alternatives to the script tag mentioned in the Question [How to use jQuery (or any JS lib) in initial post rendering of Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/54106/154) that you could explore.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ltng:require`.

> ltng:require enables you to load external CSS and JavaScript libraries
>   after you upload them as static resources.

```
<ltng:require 

   styles="{!$Resource.SLDSv1 + '/assets/styles/lightning-design-system-ltng.css'}"

   scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}"

   afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```

Source:- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here we need to create link or script tags dynamically in the component's controller doInit function.

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
           //
           //
        } else {
            //Create head tag dynamically
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

            //Create link or script tag dynamically
            var link = document.createElement('link');

            //Add appropriate attributes
            link.href = "/resource/bootstrap"; 
            link.rel = "stylesheet";

            head.appendChild(link);
        } 

},//Delimiter for future code
```