# Lightning Renderer External Script Dependency

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm trying to write a Lightning component renderer that has an external script dependency, specifically CKEditor. I know there's already a Lightning rich text component that uses CKEditor but it doesn't do everything I'd like it to.

I've got my own CKEditor static resource loaded by ltng:require, the problem is that neither render, rerender or afterRender have access to the script on first load using ltng:require. Is there a way to guarantee that the render is run after scripts are loaded?

I've tried the doneRendering event but it is still undefined and my understanding is that dom manipulation shouldn't be done outside of the renderer

```
({
render: function(component, helper) {
    var ren = this.superRender();

    console.debug('Render CKEditor: '+typeof CKEDITOR);
    console.debug('Render $: '+typeof $);


    return ren
},

rerender: function(component, helper){

    this.superReRender();

    console.debug('ReRender CKEditor: '+typeof CKEDITOR);
    console.debug('ReRender $: '+typeof $);

},

afterRender: function(component, helper) {

    console.debug('afterRender CKEditor: '+typeof CKEDITOR);
    console.debug('afterRender $: '+typeof $);

}
```

})

```
<aura:component>


<ltng:require scripts="/resource/cmsltng__jqueryui/js/rendering/jquery.min.js,
     /resource/cmsltng__jqueryui/js/rendering/jquery-ui.min.js,
     /resource/cmsltng__ckedit/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" />


<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.initCKEditor}" />  

<textarea aura:id="richText"></textarea>
```

There's a similar question but the answers are stale and pre ltng:require

[How to use jQuery (or any JS lib) in initial post rendering of Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54106/how-to-use-jquery-or-any-js-lib-in-initial-post-rendering-of-lightning-compone)

Comment: [Moshe Karmel's answer] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/83393/54660) works in my end. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "afterScriptsLoaded" event that gets fired when all of your ltng:require stuff finishes loading. I suppose you can have some renderer code that runs afterSciptsLoaded. For example

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/cmsltng__jqueryui/js/rendering/jquery.min.js,
 /resource/cmsltng__jqueryui/js/rendering/jquery-ui.min.js,
 /resource/cmsltng__ckedit/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
 afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}"/>
```

And then a controller like so:

```
render: function(component, event, helper) {
    var ren = this.superRender();
    //etc...
    return ren
},
afterLoad: function(component, event, helper) {
    this.render(component, event, helper);
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that and it works. My only concern now is that it's bad form to modify the dom there. Mind you it seems like using any external scripts while possible is bad form.

Comment: Have an attribute on your component such as `scriptsLoaded` that gets set to true in the `afterLoad` event, and then force a re-render. Have your renderer/rerenderer check that attribute and if it is true, execute the editor code?

Comment: As an aside CKeditor has some security issues with locker service that I don't think are being resolved so CKEditor in lightning is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

**this.superRender()** in controller won't work. Try this instead.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component>
        <ltng:require scripts="/resource/CKEditor" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" />  
        <aura:attribute name="isCKEditorLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    afterLoad: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isCKEditorLoaded", true);
    }
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
    modifyDom: function(component) {
        if(component.get("v.isCKEditorLoaded")) {
            //Do the required DOM modification
        }

    }
})
```

**Renderer:**

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        helper.modifyDom(component);
    }
})
```